# Image specific URL link not loaded in image view in android

Tags: java, android

when i load Image URL into ImageView it's working fine.
but i have specific url it's not showing in imageview but it shows in web browser.

How i can display image using fresco / picasso / glide For android.

Image link is - https://www.tiket.com/img/business/m/i/business-mirahhotelbanyuwangi-hotel-banyuwangi138.jpg

Thank you

```
 final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .protocols(Collections.singletonList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
                .callTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();

        final Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this)
                .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
                .build();

        Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
```

// Also check without set setSingletonInstance but not working

```
Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(imgURL)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_no_image)
                    .into(ivPhoto);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Comment: @Tigger If you don't know then DON'T mark as Duplicate.

If you have any solution then write your code with screen shot

Answer (score 0):

With Glide you can use

```
Glide
.with(activity)
.load("https://www.tiket.com/img/business/m/i/business-mirahhotelbanyuwangi-hotel-banyuwangi138.jpg")
.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_no_image)
.into(ivPhoto);
```

also use

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"(if android device version is 8+)
```

inside `<application>` tag in Android Manifest